# Magento - How to validate my radio button?

Tags: magento, radio-button

in my custom module, I have a form which has radio buttons.
When I click the submit button it does not validate the radio button.

```
<?php
$question = Mage::getModel('emme_question/question')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
$answers = $question->getSelectedAnswersCollection();
?>
<h4><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($question->getValue()); ?></h4>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($answers as $answer): ?>
<li>
<label><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($answer->getValue()) ?></label>
<input class="required required-field" type="radio" name="my_custom_answer" value="<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>" required>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

and

```
    <?php
// app/code/local/Envato/Custompaymentmethod/Model/Paymentmethod.php
class Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Model_Paymentmethod extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {
  protected $_code  = 'custompaymentmethod';

  public function validateRadioIsSelected()
  {
    $var options = $$('input.Classname');
    for( i in options ) {
        if( options[i].checked == true ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
   }

  public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
  {
    return Mage::getUrl('custompaymentmethod/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => false));
  }
}
```

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'options' (T_STRING) in /home/mmstore9/public_html/demo/app/code/local/Envato/Custompaymentmethod/Model/Paymentmethod.php on line 27*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved

```
    public function validate()
    {
      foreach (Mage::getModel('emme_question/question')->load(1)->getSelectedAnswersCollection() as $answer) 
      {
        if ($answer->getIsCorrect()) 
        {
            if ($answer->getId() == $_POST['my_custom_answer']) 
            {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Risposta esatta');
            } else 
                {
                        Mage::throwException('Risposta sbagliata!');
                }
        }   
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this magetno default validation class to validate the radio button

`validate-one-required-by-name`

OR

`validate-one-required`

Comment: @Quaisar

as suggested , so I modified the code

    <?php
    ....
    <input class="validate-one-required" type="radio" name="my_custom_answer" value="<?php echo $answer->getId() ?>"
    </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>

But the radio buttons still are disabled

http://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Rs2.jpg

Comment: @Benix89 can put the whole so i can check what is the problem